# While loop freezes game in Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, while-loop

I've always struggled with while loops because they barely ever work for me. They always cause my Unity3D application to freeze, but in this instance I really need it to work:

```
bool gameOver = false;
bool spawned = false;
float timer = 4f;

void Update () 
{
    while (!gameOver)
    {
        if (!spawned)
        {
            //Do something
        }
        else if (timer >= 2.0f)
        {
            //Do something else
        }
        else
        {
            timer += Time.deltaTime;
        }
    }
}
```

Ideally, I want those if statements to run as the game runs. Right now it crashes the program and I know it's the while loop which is the problem because it freezes anytime I uncomment it out.

Comment: your question is unanswerable. Please create a [MCVE]

Comment: `while` loops themselves won't crash a program; please describe your problem in more detail, including what the debugger reports, such as the line of the crash, variable values at that point, etc.

Comment: @bolov and Ken, guys, he's referring to scripting in Unity3D, so it is definitely answerable.

Comment: this is quite unclear for me .

Comment: Do you really need a `while` loop? Why not `if (!gameOver)`?

Comment: If that is a MonoBehavior then the Update function will be called each frame. To work with that you most likely want something like `if(!gameOver) { do your stuff }`

Comment: Thanks Lece, that makes sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Update()` is called **every frame**, so you should not use a `while` loop in it except in exceptional circumstances. This is because the game screen freezes until the loop is exited.

Further reading: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html

Instead, either use a coroutine as @Programmer has done, or use an if/switch statement instead, with a boolean check.

i.e.

```
bool gameOverActionDone = false;
void Update () 
{
    if (!gameOver && !gameOverActionDone)
    {
        if (!spawned)
        {
            //Do something
            gameOverActionDone = true;
        }
        else if (timer >= 2.0f)
        {
            //Do something else
            gameOverActionDone = true;
        }
        else
        {
            timer += Time.deltaTime; //either keep this here, or move it out if the if condition entirely
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

If you want to use a variable to control a `while` loop and wait in that `while` loop then do it in a coroutine function and `yield` after each wait. If you don't yield, it will wait too much and Unity will freeze. On mobile devices like iOS, it would crash.

```
void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(sequenceCode());
}

IEnumerator sequenceCode()
{
    while (!gameOver)
    {
        if (!spawned)
        {
            //Do something
        }
        else if (timer >= 2.0f)
        {
            //Do something else
        }
        else
        {
            timer += Time.deltaTime;
        }

        //Wait for a frame to give Unity and other scripts chance to run
        yield return null;
    }
}
```